# Is a performance test of existing answers a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

Today I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423376/2333214) and this [post posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221100/2333214).

This post doesn't add a new answer to the actual question being asked. It's a performance test result of existing answers and OP clearly says

> Just for the sake of performance, I tested **all the answers given here**

(emphasis mine)

and then declares an existing answer as the winner of his tests.

Well, this post does add some useful information (*in my opinion*), but the question was not about the performance of possible ways to do x.

I know it's a bit old one, my question isn't about this specific post -

I'm curious what the community thinks about such posts (*answers*?).
So, are they considered valid answers..? If not, how should such posts be handled in general..?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not performance answers are accepted, I think his answer is just silly. None of the 4 tests he has are logically doing the same thing. Given any of the two tests, you can find an input which results in two different outputs. /rant

Comment: @Stryner but an educated rant. IMO Its more silly because it doesn't answer a question asked. Its basically someone posting their "work" for the sake of it being stored somewhere.

Comment: Definitely not an answer, deleted.

Comment: @meagar What you deleted shows at least four ways of doing what the question is asking - how is it not an answer? You may think it is misleading or inaccurate => downvote. But deletion?

Comment: I hope the answerer gave attribution. But if the result was that one or more ways to solve the problem were considerably faster/slower than the others I would regard it as important, regardless of what the question said.

Comment: @meagar I agree it's not a genuine answer and should be removed but what if it was a community wiki?

Comment: Err, if the answer was rewritten as *"The best way to do this is the Split and Pop method because it is the fastest. <Insert performance tests.>"*, would anyone be complaining that it is "not an answer"? (cc @meagar)

Comment: @meagar You really are supposed to know better than answering this question the way you have. To quote the placeholder text you see before typing a comment: "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: So what about [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35359918/1048572)? Is it any better?

Comment: @meagar - I strongly disagree with deleting that answer. If there's a problem with the post, the problem is the question itself... it's asking a question to which there are many "correct" answers. If anything, that post was one of the few to actually provide a useful answer... what's the most efficient of the many options? That's extremely relevant information to other users who may visit the post. I thought mods were only supposed to act when there was an extremely clear violation. At worst, this answer was in a gray zone. Let the community do its job and downvote or vote to delete.

Comment: @JDB We routinely clean up answers which aren't actually *answers*, they are commentary on other answers. This is *exactly* what the answer in question is: Commentary on *other answers*. Anyways, I'm not strongly on either side of the argument here, I will happily restore the question and let the community cast votes as they will. But ask yourself what kind of precedent  this sets; should we allow such answers on new questions, going forward? Are people going to feel like they should be posting similar "summary" answers on other already well-answered questions?

Comment: @meagar - Again, I think the issue here was with the question. It didn't set good bounds on an acceptable answer, so you end up with way too many possible answers. Was basically a "what's your favorite approach". That answer summarizes some of the others and provides a metric for choosing one. So in this specific case, I'd say that it is most certainly an acceptable answer.

Comment: @JDB I'm missing something... where the question mention that it accept "favorites"?

Comment: @Braiam - By "*basically*", I mean that, while the phrase was never used, the effect was the same. The question doesn't define the OS, the runtime (browser or Node?) nor a metric by which to measure answers against one another. The question may as well have been "What's your favorite way to parse a file path into folder/file names using Javascript?" and the answers would have been the same.

Comment: @JDB that is enough to close the question as too broad, if that was the case. Without enough constrains that prevent disparates answers, the question as it is doesn't stand up to Stack Overflow standards which tend to attract low quality answers, hence closing is the next step.

Answer (score 51):

I think this is pedantic - although the answer may not answer the question directly it is definitely adding information that is related to the question. The goal of SO is to help the community in general and someone looking to do the same thing may have performance considerations in mind and find the answer helpful.

I can't judge its quality so if you feel like it is misleading because it is not testing performance properly, comment and downvote.

But I think deleting is the wrong course of action here.

Comment: Yes indeed. Many late and slightly irrelevant answers ale helped me in the past, as well as answers evaluating other answers.

Comment: Agreed; it was clearly useful to at least 12 other people. I have always found those types of performance-based answers useful. By deleting it, a precedent is set. Shouldn't the other non-answers on that question be deleted now as well? The community should handle these types of answers and vote accordingly rather than a moderator.

Comment: The original asker may not have cared (or have indicated they cared) about performance, and for this particular question, it may rarely be an issue, but someday, someone that comes across such questions might, so allowing such  "meta" answer seems worthwhile.  (As @assylias says, if this _particular_ meta-answer is poor, comment or downvote, but allowing this type of answer feels useful).

Comment: Actually, the *express* goal of the site when it was created was explicitly to ensure that when looking at a question the **answer to that question** was what was most predominately displayed to future readers, and that all other interactions with the question that aren't posting an answer be kept separate from the answers.

Comment: @Servy The real **original and current goal** to is to help programmers find the information they need. What you stated is just a mechanism to help the goal. The post under discussion helps with that goal, and the goal is more important than the mechanism. Your comment fails for the particular post being discussed anyway, since it copies four proposed answers into it. It is thus arguably the most complete answer on the page.

Comment: @jpmc26 Plagiarizing a bunch of content and adding *entirely off topic* information is not adding anything useful to that question.  Additionally, answers (at least answer of any real quality) are more than just their code.  Again, a *key goal* of the site when it was created was to have very focused questions with very accessible answers to those questions.  It was specifically designed to replace forums where there was tons of information all over the place, and even if much of it was useful, it wasn't *answering the question* which is what someone who goes to that question generally wants.

Comment: @Servy The issue of plagiarizing can be solved by adding appropriate citations, and that issue is off topic for this question. Performance is most certainly on topic in any situation where several competing answers do what the asker wants; it distinguishes them. We *frequently* add information the asker didn't explicitly request. Look at **any** XY problem. The idea we shouldn't is *nonsense*. Furthermore, having four competing answers in separate posts is far more "all over the place" than having them gathered in a single answer, so from *your own argument*, this is an improvement.

Comment: @jpmc26 The idea that performance is *always* a concern of *any* question is nonsense.  So long as none of the perform so poorly as to because a notable problem, the performance is *irrelevant*. This is just pointless micro-optimization.  It's entertaining, but not useful at all.  Purely a distraction. It's entertainment; nothing more. If there were actually significant performance differences such that it would make one a practical solution and others not, or if the code in question is in a highly performance sensitive situation *as is indicated by the question*, **then** it becomes relevant.

Comment: @jpmc26 As far as putting them in the same answer, no, taking the code from 4 answers and copy-pasting it into one answer isn't improving anything.  It's only removing relevant information. It prevents the community's judgement of the best answer from rising to the top, and the others from being ordered based on their evaluated quality, it removes them from their context, and the community's commentary of it, it adds noise as all of a sudden they're lots of additional duplicate information for readers to sort out, etc.  Just going around copy-pasting answers together is *not* adding value.

Comment: @Servy - While I agree that the answer could have been a lot better and added far more information, one can hardly argue that it doesn't address the question. Giving the OP additional information useful for selecting between the given answers is absolutely an answer. You might not think it's a useful answer and you are welcome to downvote it, but it's definitely an answer to the question. (Otherwise every time someone asks "*How do I find DIV tags with regex?*" and someone else answers "*Don't. Use a parser.*", we'd have to delete it for technically not answering the question.)

Comment: @JDB This post is just commentary on *other* answers.  The fact that it has copy-pasted (without attribution, I might add) the content of several other answers doesn't make it an answer.  Commentary on other answers belongs in comments, not in an answer.  You don't post an answer when you want to "address" the question.  You post an answer to answer the question.  You use comments to provide information relevant to the question or other answers when you're not actually adding a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Servy - Scenario: I come to a question late and see that an approach that I'd have recommended has already been posted as an answer by another user, but the answer is, in my opinion, incomplete. I don't have a "new" answer, but I do have additional information that the OP and other users may find useful. What should I do?

Comment: @JDB That would depend on what type of information that is.  In most cases you post it as a comment to the existing answer.

Comment: @Servy - I generally agree. The argument, then, is over "what type of information" warrants a new post versus a comment. I think I've got enough perspective to write an answer now. :)

Comment: @Servy Comments are ephemeral and therefore inappropriate for content that should be long lived. I have a hard time believing *no one who will ever find that question* is interested in the performance characteristics of competing answers. If you have a problem with the quality of the answer on its own merits and deficiencies, fine, go improve it (or post a competing answer if you think it's different enough). Until you can replace the content with something superior, though, deleting it helps *no one*. Quit being pedantic about an edge case in the rules and focus on making great content.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're effectively saying that comments can be deleted, so anything that belongs in a comment should be placed in an answer instead, so that it can't be deleted.  If someone really needs to know the performance characteristics of these solutions, they can ask a question on that subject.  Saying, "It's not an answer, and it's off topic, but someone might find it interesting anyway so I don't care" doesn't make it an answer.

Comment: SO has been specifically designed as a way to provided specific answers to specific questions.  Your forum mindset of just trying to fill the page with information, without regard for having a clear answer to the question, isn't in line with the SO mindset.

Comment: @Servy It *is* an answer. It has *four* answers. All your issues are different than, "It's not an answer," so I assumed that was settled. What the devil are you talking about?

Comment: @jpmc26 Creating an answer that just plagiarizes 4 other answers isn't an answer.  If you just go around to a bunch of questions and copy-paste them into one post, you're not adding value

Comment: @Servy "Not an answer" != "does not add value." If you're going to be pedantic, at least get your terms straight. NAA is, "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question," and is mostly clarified in [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712). It means that *taken out of context*, it *still* doesn't actually contain an answer to an on topic question in the text. This one clearly contains an attempt to answer an on topic question, so NAA doesn't apply. At all. You'll have to do better if you want an excuse to delete it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Going around plagiarizing a bunch of other people's answers is not an appropriate answer, and is grounds for deletion in its own right.  But the answer isn't posted with the intention of answering the question, it's posted specifically to commentate on other answers.  It is not itself and attempt to answer the question, so it is indeed NAA.

Comment: @Servy As has *already been stated numerous times*, the copying issue is solved with appropriate citation and is *not relevant discussion for this particular meta question* (or as commentary on *this* answer), and the answer adds new information and is not simple commentary. Additionally, you clearly haven't read the link I posted or the meta questions about mods declining NAA flags, since you don't even know what NAA is for. If you're not going to take the time to understand the resources/research provided to you, then this can't possibly be a productive conversation. Have a good day.

Answer (score 16):

> This post doesn't add a new answer to the actual question being asked.

You're right, it doesn't add a *new answer*. But that's not a problem. It's only when a new post doesn't add any *new information* that it's a problem. In this case, the post doesn't add a new answer, but it definitely adds new information.

It manages to do so in a way that still answers the question as well: if all the rest of the Internet, including the other answers to the question, suddenly disappeared, and I'm looking at the question and the answer you link to, would I have an answer to that question? Yes, I would. I wouldn't need to look at any other answers to make sense of that one.

<sub>As mentioned already, it's not necessarily a *good* answer in its current form. I'm ignoring that, since that's not what your question is about.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Pedantism is a quality one would expect to see frequently in the active user base of a site like SO, and the attention to detail sets this site apart from the user boards and other sites it's replaced, so don't hate on us for caring about minutiae.

The answer under discussion is difficult to analyze because **the question itself** is not very good. It does a very poor job defining the scope (what OS? what platform?), the technologies involved (browser? node?) and the rubric by which to judge answers (performance? readability?) which, even if one does not know the answer, one could reasonably assume would be many.

This really becomes a question of how much *new information* one must add to an answer when other answers have already been posted. Typically, the accepted way to add additional context, warnings or minor tweaks is via a comment. However, sometimes there's enough additional information to warrant a new answer. Where exactly that line falls is pretty tough to call.

You can be sure that any additional information that **could easily fit within a comment** is probably not going to be well received. That's as good a rule of thumb as any other I've seen.

If you are going to post a whole new answer to an already crowded field of answers, you had really better post something worth the additional scrolling and reading. The answer in question definitely falls into a gray area. It's adding just a tiny bit more than what you could fit into a comment (where would you even put that comment?) but it's doubtful that there's enough to justify a whole new answer.

Personally, I find that answer to be just useful enough to allow, but I really wish the author had included a lot more content. Others are going to look at that answer and find it completely useless. Lesson: I'd recommend against using that answer as an example or model for future posts.

In summary, it's better to add wings to a unicorn:

[image: Twilight sparkle gets her wings.]

Then a horn to Ralph Wiggum:

[image: Ralph Wiggum with ice cream cone on his head]

Answer (score 3):

My personal objection against [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript/25221100#25221100) mentioned in the initial post above is that 
1) nothing is said about the test cases (what actual input strings those formulas are tested against)
2) nothing is said about the testing procedure itself: single run, average on 1000 runs or something else.

I think that is the main flaw.

I also like what @Stryner said about the validity of those formulas themselves.

Comment: Your "objection against this answer" is not clear when we don't know what answer you're talking about. It appears as though you're using the Your Answer section to add a comment. Use the "add a comment" link below the answer to add a comment to the answer.

Comment: @Mike they're talking about the answer being discussed in this question, and I agree with their criticism.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thank you for clarification. I thought my reference is obvious without a hyperlink for anyone who had read the initial post )))

Answer (score -1):

To borrow a bit from [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), try to figure out which fruit the answer you are looking at is.

[image]

The way I look at it, the answer you linked to is the orange in the picture.  It is nice in that it does add some value to the question.  But that wasn't even remotely the question that was asked.  No one said anything about performance.  If the question was what was "better" (assuming the question didn't get closed immediately), then a performance argument could be appropriate.  But we aren't looking at that.  We want apples.  And someone gave us an orange.

At the very least, downvote it.  If you feel strongly enough, flag it.  I would probably use a custom mod flag and explain what you are seeing.  At first glance, it looks like a valid answer, so an NAA flag would probably get declined.

In any case, don't be surprised if a flag gets declined.  This feels like one of those things where everyone's opinion might be a bit different on what to do with this.  It has been upvoted, so at least a few people have found it useful.  Does that mean it is worth keeping around, at least in some form?  Maybe.  Depends on who you ask.

If the information contained in the answer should be allowed to survive, it is probably better as a comment on the appropriate answer detailing that someone did a test and it came up that a particular answer was so much faster than the other answers.

Comment: Funny note: that "orange" is technically an apple...

Comment: IMO we should leave it there. Downvotes are fine but removing it feels like a waste. I mean the apples are already there, a free orange wouldn't hurt. ;)

Comment: IMHO it is NOT and orange, but a classification of the apples: Class "A", Class "B" and "applesauce material". Although technically it may not be an new answer, it adds value to the post, so why remove it?

Comment: @Keale a free orange does hurt if you don't care to remove it from the basket. It sets a precedent for everyone to just start tossing around oranges where apples are asked.

Comment: To go with this analogy, the answer (now deleted) isn't an orange, it's four apples plus an orange. Those four apples make it an answer. It didn't just link to the existing answers, it included the code of the existing answers in itself.

Comment: The "Low Quality Answer" apple is actually a very good apple, since maggots only ever eat nice, organic apples.

Comment: Actually I think the answer in question (pun intentional) is really more of the "sign: apples that way."  The post tested the answers for performance and **then said "that one there."**  The post is still a bit orange around the edges and still "not an answer."

Comment: @Draco18s That doesn't hold if the answer really did include the important code from the other answers, as an answer based on a link is perfectly acceptable if it includes the important info from the linked page.

Comment: @NathanArthur Old comment is a year+ old. I only vaguely remember this post.

Comment: @Draco18s Oop, didn't notice. My bad. :)

Comment: @NathanArthur Its fine, sometimes I don't notice either, I just didn't have a meaningful reply, because Present-Me doesn't remember what Past-Me was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336313/621962) pretty useful... and I actually provided one of [the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335796/621962) on that question.

However, in that particular case, the questioner specifically asked about performance (emphasis mine):

> What is the most elegant, reliable and **efficient** way to get the grandparent's first child in JQuery?

Your question makes no mention of performance... so, an answer focused entirely on the performance of other answers makes little sense.

Comment: So removing the word "efficient" from the question would make the answer you mention less useful?

Comment: It's not about utility. It's about whether an answer applies, contextually, to a question. And yes, certain words can affect context.

Comment: I'm baffled, where this question says it wants a comparison or other kind of metric besides... just obtaining the goal?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is an answer. It does not immediately warrant deletion.

A straight up plagiarized answer that copied the most popular upvoted answers on the post, pasted them in without citation or care, and proceeded to show some simple statistics that have no relevance. At which point, it warrants deletion.

Comment: Plagiarism is a serious accusation. Credit is indeed not given in the manner suggested by SO, and that may warrant editing or deletion, but it's still not plagiarism: the answer does not claim or try to claim the code snippets as its own. It starts off by saying the code comes from the other answers.

Answer (score -4):

Quite simple: downvote it if you feel the post does not have anything to do with the question. If you think the information is usefull use the up-vote button as also mentioned in the tooltip-text.

To honor the other answers simply up- and downvote how usefull they are to you not considering any performance-implications that have not been asked. You have to consider every post on its own and rate is as such. You cannot do anything for or against *OPs decision* to accept an answer, however you may rate those *you* think are of any value or of no value at all.

I doubt there is any appropriate flag that you can use to moderate such a behaviour.

Comment: The question here is whether or not *it is even an answer*, which *is* highly relevant to it being flagged.  It's not simply a question of whether or not it's a quality answer.

Answer (score -7):

Lets go with *reductio ad absurdum* in this case. Would anyone want a comparative test of all the answers on Stack Overflow? The shy more 18 million of them? How about those answers that can't be measured by any stretch? Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179147/792066)? This smell like madness.

How about those comparisons that depends on other factors? For example A is faster than B if X condition is met otherwise A is several times slower. A user trusting on those test may select A when their context have unfavorable variables, but the users themselves can already do a comparative test of all the answers and have more accurate results since it's in the context they need it to be.

Now does it ever answer the question "How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?"? I copy and paste the "answer" on the next multibillion project I will have, I will have problems. Remember how the site gravitates around "solutions"... well, this answer solves nothing. Its existence is a duplication of content on the same page which predates for 2-5 years. Can someone claim that they do a service after 2 years that the content was there and nobody felt the need of a performance comparison? A comparison that even my own testing doesn't agree:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889850/792066
var substringTest = function(str) {
  return str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
};

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/423385/792066
var replaceTest = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/^.*(\\|\/|\:)/, '');
};

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/427021/792066
var execTest = function(str) {
  return /([^\\]+)$/.exec(str)[1];
};

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/424006/792066
var splitTest = function(str) {
  return str.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
};

var t0 = performance.now();
var result = substringTest(str);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
var t0 = performance.now();
var result = replaceTest(str);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
var t0 = performance.now();
var result = execTest(str);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
var t0 = performance.now();
var result = splitTest(str);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
```

Resulted in:

```
Took 0.0400 milliseconds to generate: C:\Documents and Settings\img\recycled log.jpg
Took 0.0850 milliseconds to generate: recycled log.jpg
Took 0.0500 milliseconds to generate: recycled log.jpg
Took 0.0200 milliseconds to generate: recycled log.jpg
```

I say that the first test is bogus, as it didn't obtain the desired result, bobince answer is still the fastest, the second place is bogus, and the third was a little slower in this run too. The exec is by far the slowest. Nobody will ever know if the difference is due my methodology or other reasons, as the answer doesn't even include the methodology employed for the performance test.

Which leads me to the conclusion that, such comparisons, are totally worthless.

Comment: You set your `str` wrong. this is why you get the wrong results.
And to get more accurate results you should run them x100 times in a random order and then print the average.

Comment: @Danpe **"You set your str wrong."** I'm copy-n-pasting the [exact same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25221100/792066) discussed in the question. So, if some code is wrong, is the one that made the comparison in first place, and just supports my argument that this kind of answers are unacceptable.

Comment: The answer is correct and you copied it correctly, but the `str` you are sending to the functions is incorrect which makes you generate `C:Documents and Settingsimgecycled log.jpg`.....

Comment: @Danpe is not incorrect. I copied the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423376/792066) given in the question.

Comment: Yes... but it should be `var str = 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\img\\recycled log.jpg'`

Comment: @Danpe the heck, I need to escape backlash inside a quote?! Anyways, the first one is still bugus.