# Reloading an answer-link does not update the position

Tags: bug, design

1. First, I read an answer, like 
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350032/772868
   . The compact link redirects to
   `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316670/is-a-performance-test-of-existing-answers-a-valid-answer/350032#350032`.
   The page is loaded and after being loaded, the precise actual page position seems to be adjusted such that I can read the answer easily.
2. Then, I scroll up and down that page looking at other answers.
3. I now want to go back to the original answer, having lost where it was.
4. So I reload the page, in the hope that this will readjust the page to again see the original answer.
5. However, I am stuck where I was at 2.

I rather expect that in 5 I am at the same position as after 1.

(FF 52.0.1 64-bit)

Comment: Just click into the url and press return. I don't think that SE will or can do anything about that, because it is your browser who remembers where you were.

Comment: That does not work either. Note that the `#`-URL does encode the very position!

Comment: This is a browser issue; it makes assumptions about what you wanted from the page. Better to go back in your browser history and click the link again, or remove the `#...` anchor and then add it again.

Comment: @false: `#...` encodes a named element in the page. Your browser is free to ignore that on certain actions however, returning you to the position you were last at when viewing the page rather than the named element.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I had the impression that even going to # is no longer the simple built-in operation: First the page is positioned as if the SO-banner was not there, only then the page is adjusted (in 1).

Comment: @false: it's more complicated than that. I regularly have to scroll anyway, because images in posts above the position of the answer I want to look at are loaded late enough to push the posts down. The positioning can take place *before* all resources have loaded.

Comment: *"That does not work either"* - It works for me (also on Firefox)